# Creating duplicates of data frame rows based on a count variable

Tags: r

[image]

I have a data that has 3 columns (city, score, number_of_students who get this score):

```
city      score       number_of_students
NYC        83              3000
NYC        94              220005
NYC        76              203
...
Chicago    92              450113 
Chicago    64              302
Chicago    98              47
Chicago    79              500021
...
```

Note that there are only two cities (NYC and Chicago)

How can I parse this file in **R** to make it look like this:

```
City     Score 
NYC       83
NYC       83
... (3000 rows with 'NYC 83')
NYC       94
NYC       94
...(76 rows with 'NYC 94')
```

same for Chicago.

So I want in my new data table, every row is one student, and there are two columns: "city" shows whether this student is from NYC or Chicago; "Score" shows the score of this student.

How can I do this in **R**?

Comment: how is the desired format more useful than what you have now

Answer (score 2):

```
data<-data.frame(city=c("NYC","Chicago"),score=c(83,94),number=c(5,10))
data[rep(rownames(data), data$number), ]
```

Comment: i get "first element used of 'each' argument"