# R Check for levels within a group and duplicate row if not present

Tags: r, duplicates

I have a problem with in Shiny which I will show in a simple example:

I have the following data:

```
Group<-c("A","A","B","C","C","D")
Value<-c(1,2,6,7,3,9)

df<-data.frame(Group, Value)

  Group Value 
     A     1   
     A     2   
     B     6   
     C     7   
     C     3   
     D     9
```

Then I add a row to see how many reps a group has:

```
df$num <- ave(df$Value, df$Group,  FUN = seq_along)

  Group Value num
     A     1   1
     A     2   2
     B     6   1
     C     7   1
     C     3   2
     D     9   1
```

Now, I would like it, to check if the group contains a 2nd rep, and if not, duplicate the 1st row of the group (containing num=1) and setting num to 2.
So I would like to end up with:

```
  Group Value num
     A     1   1
     A     2   2
     B     6   1
     B     6   2 #this row is added
     C     7   1
     C     3   2
     D     9   1
     D     9   2 #this row is added
```

I have tried to search for solution, but I mainly ended up with subject like a condition that is [based on a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29424290/creating-duplicates-of-data-frame-rows-based-on-a-count-variable), rather than conditions within a group.

Could someone help me? I would appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can this code do the trick ?

```
res <- lapply(unique(df$Group), function(x){
  a <- df[df$Group == x, ]
  if(nrow(a) == 1) {
    a <- a[rep(row.names(a), 2), ]
    a$num <- c(1:2)
  }
  a
})
do.call(rbind, res)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I just came across an extra problem, I tried to change your answer but I can't.... what if this is my dataset:

Comment: Sorry, again:
@Pauline Thank you! This works perfectly :) 
I just ran into a new problem, would you know how it works when I have the following data:
Group1<-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Group2<-c("A","A","B","B","A","A", "B")
Value<-c(1,2,6,7,3,9,6)
df<-data.frame(Group1,Group2, Value)
df

and now I would like to do the same as before but now it would search for duplicates of Group2 within Group1?

Thanks again for you answer, it really helps me out!

Comment: There is probably a simplier way to do this but I think this works :
res <- lapply(unique(df$Group1), function(x){
  int_res <- lapply(unique(df[df$Group1 == x, "Group2"]), function(z) {
    a <- df[df$Group1 == x & df$Group2 == z, ]
    if(nrow(a) == 1) {
      a <- a[rep(row.names(a), 2), ]
    }
    a
  })
  do.call(rbind, int_res)
})
do.call(rbind, res)